# Popup function returning wrong value in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
function popup(a, b) {
    x = document.getElementById(a);
    y = document.getElementById('ze-editor').offsetWidth;
    if (x.style.display == 'none') {
        position = (b.offsetX === undefined) ? b.layerX - 50 : b.offsetX - 50;
        position = Number(position);
        console.log(b.layerX - 50);
        x.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
        if (position + x.offsetWidth + 20 > y) {
            position = position - 40;
        }
        x.style.left = position + 'px';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    $('#' + a).siblings().hide();
};
```

This code works on firefox and the console log gives me the right value of "position" on both firefox and chrome. But when it comes to x.style.left, it gives me a different value? For example, my b.layerX-50 is 249 but when the popup shows up, its left value is -37?
Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Q6D5/

Comment: can you supply a jsfiddle or add some more code to your question so we can see the it in context?

Comment: Try to change `x.setAttribute('style', 'display: block');` to `x.style.display = 'block';` and try to ensure the position to absolute: `x.style.position = 'absolute'`. Also, I can see you're already using jQuery to call the "siblings", why don't you use jQuery to do all the stuff?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work at all for me, even in Firefox. That "a" parameter is the id of a DIV, and I can't see nothing inside it.

Comment: @Buzinas I updated the link, it should work now :) If you change b.layerX - 50 for "position" in x.style.left, it works fine in chrome. I don't know what might cause the problem

Comment: Give a try using clientX instead of offsetX!